# jQuery function for onClick activation across multiple IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

When I have this code:

```
$("#someid").on('click', arrow(1));
```

I need the function to start when the user clicks an HTML element with the id of `#someid`. How can I achieve this?

Also, I want the function to start when user clicks an HTML element with the id of `#otherid`. I know that this:

```
".on('click', arrow(1));"
```

is a named event, but what is called? Is it called this:

```
"$("#someid")"
```

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow! please only ask one question per question. thanks!

Comment: Unstead of try understand guys reprove it without say why, that's no cool.

Comment: And please use a proper title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#someid"); // here you are making a new jQuery object, passing in a selector
```

If you wanted to select multiple ID's, just use commas:

```
$('#someid, #otherid');
```

Comment: thanks, that helped, ill mark you as problem solver in 10 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't the exact question you asked...

I don't think this is doing what you think it's doing:

```
$("#someid").on('click', arrow(1));
```

What does `arrow(1)` return?  A function?  This line of code isn't scheduling `arrow(1)` to run when the element is clicked.  This is *invoking* `arrow(1)` and scheduling its *return value* to run when the element is clicked.

If you wanted to reference just the function `arrow` then you'd reference that directly as the argument to the `on` function:

```
$("#someid").on('click', arrow);
```

As for passing an argument to the `arrow` function, there are a number of approaches and what would be best for your code would require some more context about your code and how you structure it.  Perhaps the `1` value can be extracted from the `#someid` element in some way?  Or selected from some other location?  We can't know, but it's worth investigating.